# Having problem to return the count value but works well on SQL

Tags: python, pyspark

I have this query that has been written in SQL and it works but I want to write it in pyspark but it's not returning the desired output

SQL code

```
 select count(distinct(studen_num)) from user
 where email is null
 and matnumber is null
 and (academic_history is null or exists (academic_history, x -> x.grade = "A" and 
 x.level is null))
 and graduation_status is null
 and exists (investigated_result, x -> x.panelseated[0].grade = "1" and x.level is null)
```

This is what I have done

```
 df_count_student = df.filter(df.email.isNull() & df.matnumber.isNull() & 
 (df.academic_history.isNull() | (array_contains(df.academic_history.grade, "A") & 
 df.academic_history.level.isNull())) & (array_contains(df.investigated_result.panelseated[0].grade, "1") & 
 df.investigated_result.level.isNull()))

 display(df_count_student(countDistinct())
```

The problem is that I count display was 0 but got the right value when tried in the SQL code.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data to recreate this query output

Comment: The data is something that can be made public because is academic data of people.